# Mercurial versions in server and local machine

Tags: mercurial

Does Mercurial have some minimum version control? Like if I have too old version in local machine it will output some error message when trying to connect to server?

Or is there possiblity to configure server side Mercurial to accept only version 4.0 or newer Mercurial versions from local machines?

Comment: Why worry about specific versions?  Instead worry about capability.  Presumably you want to use a newer version because it has a particular capability you need -- if the client can't support the prerequisite capability then it can't be allowed to check in.  If older versions support the capability you need, why bother?

Comment: Specific version isn't problem. But if we have had situation where client version was too new but error message didn't tell that. So I thought if there is a way to pretend this.

Comment: And we are having issue where some of our repositories get corrupted few times a year. We don't know the root cause for that and we don't even know when repositories get corrupted. We suppose one reason can be too old Mercurial version 3.7. So if we update server version we would like to force clients to update also.

Comment: Any mercurial client should in principle be able to talk to any mercurial server and vice versa. It's - as said above - more a question of the capabilities which you (want to) need. Make sure your server does not run on a network volume and has exclusive access to the repos it manages..

Answer (score 0):

Any Mercurial client should be able to connect to any Mercurial server.  You might be missing features but the basics, like `push`, `pull`, and `clone` should work.

Comment: At least this isn't true in our case. We have [Hglab](https://hglabhq.com/) v1.8 which has "built-in Mercurial" (v3.3 or older). And if we use newer Mercurial than v3.8 in client server responses `"abort: 'http://url.to/repo' does not appear to be an hg repository: html page from Hglab"`.

Comment: I can't comment on third party solutions.  I was just talking about "vanilla" Mercurial.